# React Router Passing information

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having trouble passing a parameter through the react-router, 
I am getting a type error saying this.props.match is undefined when I have this as my router =>

```
const App = () =>
<Router>
<div className="app">

  <Navigation />
  <Jumbotron>
  <hr/>
  <Route exact path={"/players/:name"} component={PlayerPage} />
  <hr/>
  </Jumbotron>

</div>
</Router>
export default withAuthentication(App);
```

And then I do this in my page

```
class PlayerPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params.name);
```

I have looked through the site and every answer says to do the above to pass information through the router. When I navigate to the page /players/Bob everything in the componentDidMount() loads that is not dependent on this.props.match.param.name.

Error:
TypeError: this.props.match is undefined

How do I get this.props.match.param.name to have the string "Bob"?

Comment: You need to wrap your component with [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

Comment: @Guillaume no you don't need that to get params

Comment: is `match` undefined? or are is it that you're misspelling `params`. missing an `s`

Comment: oh sorry i misspelled it when i put it in here, yes it is that match is undefined, a Type Error